# Outputs of "Strahler Order" and "Channel Network and Drainage Basins" different despite same threshold

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, saga, hydrology, strahler

I ran the Strahler Order and the Channel Network and Drainage Basins tools both with threshold at 8 and using the same filled DEM. The results differ as shown below.

**Strahler Order raster (only showing cells 8 and above via Raster Calculator)**

OpenStreetMap shows there's a "West Elk Creek" in the middle of the map
[image]

Hillshade
[image]

**Channels shapefile (from Channel Network and Drainage Basins tool)**

OpenStreetMap
[image]

Hillshade
[image]

If you want to replicate, the 1-meter DEM is from https://apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader/#/ and location is -107.253388,38.602579.

And this is the **Channels shapefile (from Channel Network and Drainage Basins tool) with threshold at 4**. Somehow the tool doesn't include the West Elk Creek.
[image]